# Create After Update Trigger that fires only when a certain field has changed value

Tags: database-trigger

Can someone please tell me why this does not work and how to make it work?
I am using this in an AFTER UPDATE trigger in SQL 2005.

```
IF (DELETED.[Lot Price - 1] <> INSERTED.[Lot Price 1])
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [T - Quotes - History]
           ([QuotePK]
           ,[Record #]
           ,[Date]
           ,[Quoted By]
           ,[[Lot Price - 1])
SELECT 
           [QuotePK]
           ,[Record #]
           ,[Date]
           ,[Quoted By]
           ,[Lot Price - 1]

FROM INSERTED
```

I get the following 2 errors: The multi-part identifier "DELETED.QuotePK" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.QuotePK" could not be bound.

I only want this trigger to fire when the [Lot Price - 1] value has changed from its previous value.

Thanks